# Is “bête chevronné” correct for "seasoned/experienced beast?" I was told I need an extra “e”

Tags: adjectifs, accord

Is the expression "bête chevronné" correct for "seasoned/experienced beast"? I was told I need an extra e.

Comment: Stéphane Gimenez has the correct answer here under, but I have my doubts about the idiom as a whole. I'm not sure how idiomatic "seasoned beast" is in English (having a bit of context might also help understanding if we're talking about an actual beast of a figurative one), but "bête chevronnée" looks like a poor word-to-word translation to me...

Comment: @LaurentS: "seasoned beast" or "experienced beast" is totally unidiomatic in English.

Answer (score 4):

You do. Adjectives agree with the gender (and number) of the nouns they qualify. Since *bête* is a feminine noun, the feminine form of the adjective is required, which in this case is spelled [*chevronnée*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chevronn%C3%A9), with an extra *e*.

The agreement is purely grammatical as “bête” (feminine) may figuratively refer to a person or live being, or entity of any biological or attributed gender.

Answer (score 0):

"Chevronné(e)" is used for **persons**, especially in the context of their professionnalism, and at that, only when their profession involves a rather important amount of knowledge; one will not ever say something like "une caissière chevronnée"; it means "fully skilled", "well versed in the subtleties of one's profession"; you could say , however, "un charpentier chevronné". It seems that what you mean is rather "une **bête endurcie**", that is a strong beast, trained to bear a burden without failing; in any case this corresponds more to "seasoned" than "experienced".

The added e is justified by the gender of "bête", which is a feminine word in French; in French there is a rule of agreement  of a noun with its adjective, in gender and in number; e is added to obtain the feminine form of the adjective and s the plural; thus, if the beast were a donkey you'd write "**un âne endurci** ("âne" is masculine, so, no e); if there were several beasts you'd have to say "**plusieurs bêtes endurci*es***" (first e and then s, never the other way).

Comment: You might have commented the question for clarification. There is no evidence beast represent an animal in the question; On the opposite, I have only seen *seasoned* applied to persons so *beast* should likely be understood as slang for "very impressive person", a meaning that can be found in French slang too (*Ce gars là, c'est une bête en math*). *Bête chevronnée* is nevertheless odd though.

Comment: @jlliagre No explicit evidence, true; inferred it could not be anything else than an animal; only meaning I can find that is related to humans, no slang: brute; true, use of "seasoned" acknowledged for persons only (and wood);  no trace of "impressive person" for "beast"; familiar with "la bête !" in french argot (men with impressive muscles); nothing in the TLFi; I do find  "personne très douée dans un domaine" in reverso;  a figurative beast maybe; now, the answer's success or lack of it might make things clearer; would have asked  precisions or abstained if not convinced "beast" an animal.

Comment: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=beast

Comment: Un charpentier chevronné ! Ah ha, c'est un comble !

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Tranquillisez-vous, je ne vois ni la paille dans l'œil du voisin ni la poutre dans le mien, que le charpentier classique, auquel, il est vrai, on n'a plus trop à faire appel de nos jours!

Comment: Less than a week ago, as a matter of fact, the Association of Tennis Professionals had an article about a retiring veteran, [Max ‘The Beast’ Mirnyi](https://www.atpworldtour.com/en/news/mirnyi-announces-retirement-2018).